# Program returns character instead of string

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I have a problem with my program. It suppose to return string according to chosen switch, but it only returns all the times "D". I dont know what is wrong. Im also may mess something up with while loop.

> main.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "WordTools.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char line[200];
    char temp[200];
    int i = 0;

    printf("Enter a string: \n");
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line),stdin)){
        temp[i] = strdup(line);
        i++;
    }

    switch (argc > 1 && argv[1][1]) {
    case 'l':
    case 'L':
        printf("%c", makeLower(line));
        break;
    case 'u':
    case 'U':
        printf("%c", makeUpper(line));
        break;
    case 'c':
    case 'C':
        printf("%c", makeChange(line));
        break;
    case 'n':
    case 'N':
        printf("%c", makeName(line));
        break;
    default:
        printf("%c", makeUpper(line));
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> worldtools.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "WordTools.h"

char makeLower(char *s) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++){
        s[i] = tolower(s[i]);
    }
    return s;
}

char makeUpper(char *s) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++){
        s[i] = toupper(s[i]);
    }
    return s;
}

char makeChange(char *s) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++){
        if ((s[i] >= 65) && (s[i] <= 90)) s[i] = tolower(s[i]);
        else if ((s[i] >= 97) && (s[i] <= 122)) s[i] = toupper(s[i]);
    }
    return s;
}

char makeName(char *s) {
    int i;
    s[0]=toupper(s[0]);
    for(i = 1; s[i] != '\0'; i++){
        s[i] = tolower(s[i]);
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: `temp[i] = strdup(line);` compiler din't scream?

Comment: The same with the `make*` functions, the compiler doesn't shout at you for returning a `char *` when you declare the functions to return a single `char`?

Comment: I have 0 warnings. How it should look like then?

Comment: In the `main` function, what is the type of `temp`? What is the type of `temp[i]`? What type is `strdup` returning? Are the type of `temp[i]` and the returned type of `strdup` the same? Same with the `make*` functions. What is the type of `s`? What is the functions declared to return? Are those types the same?

Comment: A couple of other notes: What is the use of `temp` in the `main` function? And don't use [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). And take a look at the [`isupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isupper) and [`islower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isupper) functions.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I still cant figure out how while loop should look like. Im know im doing something wrong, but still dont know what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

Check the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char makeLower(char *s) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++){
        s[i] = tolower(s[i]);
    } // Big mistake: there is no point returning s, because we are operating on the address of s, meaning, whatever changes you make, it stays!
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char line[200];

    if (argc > 1) {  
      strcat(line, argv[1]); // this is just a quick way to test your code. You need to do something, cleaner. But, basically, it takes the arguments from your terminal and saves it as line.
      printf("%s\n", line);
    }
    else return 0; // exit code

    makeLower(line); // here we make changes to line, the line variable is permanently changed.
    printf("%s\n", line);


    return 0;
}
```

I'm using ubuntu. So to run this code in terminal I write:

```
aykjas@asdk:~/Desktop$ gcc main.c -o main
aykjas@asdk:~/Desktop$ ./main HELLO
```

The output is, as you can see, changed to lower:

```
HELLO
hello
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Sadly, it crashes now.

Comment: Now, it should not crash! :D